# KeyDown event not letting timer start

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to make a simple text-based spammer, but I seem to be running into an issue with some of the code under `Keydown event` not letting me start a timer.

I am relatively new to c# and c++ though I have made console applications before that was quite massive and this is my first time running into an issue like this.

I have already tried pretty much everything. I always used stack overflow for most of my questions but it doesn't seem to have an answer to my problem.

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Enabled = true;
}

private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Enabled = false;
}

private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Control && e.KeyCode.ToString() == "M") ;
    {
       timer1.Enabled == true; //right here is my issue
    }
}
```

I am trying to start my timer with the short cut key, in this case, Ctrl + M and it will then start a timer which will continue until stopped by another shortcut key (not implemented yet) or the stop button. It gives the error

> CS0201 Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Would love some help thank you in advance!

Comment: You need to use `=` instead of `==`. `timer1.Enabled = true;`

Comment: it should be `timer1.Enabled = true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
timer1.Enabled == true;
```

to

```
timer1.Enabled = true;
```

In addition, remove the semi colon at the end of your if statement. This is causing your timer to start as soon as any key is pressed.

```
if (e.Control && e.KeyCode.ToString() == "M") ;
```

to

```
if (e.Control && e.KeyCode.ToString() == "M")
```

Comment: It stopped giving me the error but as soon as i type anything in the text box it just starts going with or without me pushing start. https://gyazo.com/45dae3697c8f21c183d6a5afc0895ed4

Comment: Please provide your timer code.

Comment: ` private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SendKeys.Send(textBox1.Text);
            SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
            SendKeys.Send(textBox2.Text);
            SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
            SendKeys.Send(textBox3.Text);
            SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
        }
`